# Android Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) in WebViewCoreThre

Tags: android, webview

Using a Toshiba AT300SE-101 v4.1.1 (with others tablets it works), and a simple app, the app dies with a error:

```
06-19 11:02:12.092: A/libc(20030): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000001 (code=1), thread 20043 (WebViewCoreThre)
06-19 11:02:12.192: I/DEBUG(106): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
06-19 11:02:12.192: I/DEBUG(106): Build fingerprint: 'TOSHIBA/tostab12AL/tostab12AL:4.1.1/JRO03C/000122808.05:user/release-keys'
06-19 11:02:12.192: I/DEBUG(106): pid: 20030, tid: 20043, name: WebViewCoreThre  >>> com.example.prueba <<<
06-19 11:02:12.192: I/DEBUG(106): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000001
06-19 11:02:12.262: I/DEBUG(106):     r0 73054386  r1 bd895084  r2 00000000  r3 b57bdfff
06-19 11:02:12.262: I/DEBUG(106):     r4 00000001  r5 00000000  r6 00000010  r7 73054386
06-19 11:02:12.262: I/DEBUG(106):     r8 582085c0  r9 00000000  sl 5b846868  fp 5d4a9bcc
06-19 11:02:12.262: I/DEBUG(106):     ip 1545d59e  sp 5d4a9480  lr 5b10620b  pc 5b106214  cpsr 70000030
06-19 11:02:12.262: I/DEBUG(106):     d0  4307000043068e80  d1  0000000000000000
06-19 11:02:12.262: I/DEBUG(106):     d2  43068e8043068e80  d3  0000000000000000
06-19 11:02:12.262: I/DEBUG(106):     d4  0000000000000000  d5  43068e8000000000
06-19 11:02:12.262: I/DEBUG(106):     d6  0000000043070000  d7  0000000043068e80
06-19 11:02:12.262: I/DEBUG(106):     d8  0000000043068e80  d9  0000000000000000
06-19 11:02:12.262: I/DEBUG(106):     d10 0000000000000000  d11 00000000bf800000
06-19 11:02:12.262: I/DEBUG(106):     d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
06-19 11:02:12.262: I/DEBUG(106):     d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
06-19 11:02:12.262: I/DEBUG(106):     d16 0000000000000000  d17 41d4705ce5060785
06-19 11:02:12.262: I/DEBUG(106):     d18 40f7003000000000  d19 3f44adc3dd3e3800
06-19 11:02:12.262: I/DEBUG(106):     d20 3fe47ae140000000  d21 3fd51eb860000000
06-19 11:02:12.262: I/DEBUG(106):     d22 3fd3333340000000  d23 3fe3333340000000
06-19 11:02:12.262: I/DEBUG(106):     d24 3fc3333340000000  d25 3faeb851e0000000
06-19 11:02:12.262: I/DEBUG(106):     d26 40de89a0058c0000  d27 0000000000000000
06-19 11:02:12.262: I/DEBUG(106):     d28 0000000000000005  d29 0000000000000000
06-19 11:02:12.262: I/DEBUG(106):     d30 0000000000000000  d31 0000000000000000
06-19 11:02:12.262: I/DEBUG(106):     scr 60000013
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106): backtrace:
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):     #00  pc 00103214  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):     #01  pc 00189625  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):     #02  pc 0018889d  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):     #03  pc 0019043b  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):     #04  pc 001880df  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):     #05  pc 001873e3  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):     #06  pc 001c8c25  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):     #07  pc 001cb2ed  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):     #08  pc 001cdd1b  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):     #09  pc 001c8349  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):     #10  pc 001bd147  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):     #11  pc 001bd89b  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):     #12  pc 001c5d73  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):     #13  pc 001ca8dd  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):     #14  pc 001ca977  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):     #15  pc 001cdd1b  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):     #16  pc 001c8349  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):     #17  pc 001bd147  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):     #18  pc 001bd89b  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):     #19  pc 001c5d73  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):     #20  pc 001ca8dd  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):     #21  pc 001ca977  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):     #22  pc 001cdd1b  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):     #23  pc 001c8349  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):     #24  pc 001bd147  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):     #25  pc 001bd89b  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):     #26  pc 001c5d73  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):     #27  pc 001ca8dd  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):     #28  pc 001ca977  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):     #29  pc 001cdd1b  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):     #30  pc 001c8349  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):     #31  pc 001bd147  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106): stack:
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):          5d4a9440  41200000  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):          5d4a9444  42c00000  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):          5d4a9448  44674000  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):          5d4a944c  00000003  
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):          5d4a9450  00000000  
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):          5d4a9454  00000000  
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):          5d4a9458  5c16ac04  
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):          5d4a945c  5d4a965c  
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):          5d4a9460  5d4a966c  
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):          5d4a9464  5b1c166d  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):          5d4a9468  5814d5f0  
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):          5d4a946c  5b1d9fc1  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):          5d4a9470  582066c8  
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):          5d4a9474  00000000  
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):          5d4a9478  df0027ad  
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):          5d4a947c  00000000  
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):     #00  5d4a9480  00000000  
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):          5d4a9484  56be4298  
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):          5d4a9488  0000000a  
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):          5d4a948c  00000000  
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):          5d4a9490  00000001  
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):          5d4a9494  5b18c629  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):     #01  5d4a9498  00000000  
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):          5d4a949c  00000000  
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):          5d4a94a0  00000000  
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):          5d4a94a4  00000000  
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):          5d4a94a8  0000000a  
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):          5d4a94ac  582085c0  
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):          5d4a94b0  5c11cc48  
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):          5d4a94b4  5c11cbd8  
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):          5d4a94b8  5d4a9580  
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):          5d4a94bc  5c11cbd8  
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):          5d4a94c0  0000000a  
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):          5d4a94c4  5b18b8a1  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):     #02  5d4a94c8  56be4298  
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):          5d4a94cc  000000e6  
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):          5d4a94d0  00000228  
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):          5d4a94d4  0000000a  
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):          5d4a94d8  0000039d  
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):          5d4a94dc  00000113  
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):          5d4a94e0  0000000a  
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):          5d4a94e4  00000060  
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):          5d4a94e8  0000039d  
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):          5d4a94ec  56be4298  
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):          5d4a94f0  5d4a9540  
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):          5d4a94f4  5b1d5973  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):          5d4a94f8  00000000  
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):          5d4a94fc  00000000  
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):          5d4a9500  0000039d  
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):          5d4a9504  00000113  
06-19 11:02:12.272: I/DEBUG(106):          ........  ........
06-19 11:02:12.292: I/DEBUG(106): memory near r0:
06-19 11:02:12.292: I/DEBUG(106):     73054364 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
06-19 11:02:12.292: I/DEBUG(106):     73054374 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
06-19 11:02:12.292: I/DEBUG(106):     73054384 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
06-19 11:02:12.292: I/DEBUG(106):     73054394 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
06-19 11:02:12.292: I/DEBUG(106):     730543a4 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
06-19 11:02:12.292: I/DEBUG(106): memory near r1:
06-19 11:02:12.292: I/DEBUG(106):     bd895064 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
06-19 11:02:12.292: I/DEBUG(106):     bd895074 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
06-19 11:02:12.292: I/DEBUG(106):     bd895084 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
06-19 11:02:12.292: I/DEBUG(106):     bd895094 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
06-19 11:02:12.292: I/DEBUG(106):     bd8950a4 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
06-19 11:02:12.292: I/DEBUG(106): memory near r3:
06-19 11:02:12.292: I/DEBUG(106):     b57bdfdc ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
06-19 11:02:12.292: I/DEBUG(106):     b57bdfec ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
06-19 11:02:12.292: I/DEBUG(106):     b57bdffc ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
06-19 11:02:12.292: I/DEBUG(106):     b57be00c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
06-19 11:02:12.292: I/DEBUG(106):     b57be01c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
06-19 11:02:12.292: I/DEBUG(106): memory near r7:
06-19 11:02:12.292: I/DEBUG(106):     73054364 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
06-19 11:02:12.292: I/DEBUG(106):     73054374 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
06-19 11:02:12.292: I/DEBUG(106):     73054384 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
06-19 11:02:12.292: I/DEBUG(106):     73054394 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
06-19 11:02:12.292: I/DEBUG(106):     730543a4 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
06-19 11:02:12.292: I/DEBUG(106): memory near r8:
06-19 11:02:12.292: I/DEBUG(106):     582085a0 00000000 00000000 00000002 00000000  ................
06-19 11:02:12.292: I/DEBUG(106):     582085b0 00000016 00000000 00000006 0000002b  ............+...
06-19 11:02:12.292: I/DEBUG(106):     582085c0 00000001 00000000 00000000 5c159e78  ............x..\
06-19 11:02:12.292: I/DEBUG(106):     582085d0 00000001 5c159ee0 00000010 00000000  .......\........
06-19 11:02:12.292: I/DEBUG(106):     582085e0 00000028 00000013 00000006 585cbd30  (...........0.\X
06-19 11:02:12.292: I/DEBUG(106): memory near sl:
06-19 11:02:12.292: I/DEBUG(106):     5b846848 00000001 00000001 5c1453d0 5c135568  .........S.\hU.\
06-19 11:02:12.292: I/DEBUG(106):     5b846858 5c18f960 00000001 00000000 00000001  `..\............
06-19 11:02:12.292: I/DEBUG(106):     5b846868 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
06-19 11:02:12.292: I/DEBUG(106):     5b846878 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
06-19 11:02:12.292: I/DEBUG(106):     5b846888 00000000 00000000 00000000 5c9ffcb8  ...............\
06-19 11:02:12.292: I/DEBUG(106): memory near fp:
06-19 11:02:12.292: I/DEBUG(106):     5d4a9bac 00000000 00000000 ffffffff 56f8ef01  ...............V
06-19 11:02:12.292: I/DEBUG(106):     5d4a9bbc 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
06-19 11:02:12.292: I/DEBUG(106):     5d4a9bcc 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
06-19 11:02:12.292: I/DEBUG(106):     5d4a9bdc 00000000 00000000 00000000 5d4a9bf0  ..............J]
06-19 11:02:12.292: I/DEBUG(106):     5d4a9bec 00000008 0000000a 00000002 43070000  ...............C
06-19 11:02:12.292: I/DEBUG(106): memory near ip:
06-19 11:02:12.292: I/DEBUG(106):     1545d57c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
06-19 11:02:12.292: I/DEBUG(106):     1545d58c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
06-19 11:02:12.292: I/DEBUG(106):     1545d59c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
06-19 11:02:12.292: I/DEBUG(106):     1545d5ac ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
06-19 11:02:12.292: I/DEBUG(106):     1545d5bc ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
06-19 11:02:12.292: I/DEBUG(106): memory near sp:
06-19 11:02:12.292: I/DEBUG(106):     5d4a9460 5d4a966c 5b1c166d 5814d5f0 5b1d9fc1  l.J]m..[...X...[
06-19 11:02:12.292: I/DEBUG(106):     5d4a9470 582066c8 00000000 df0027ad 00000000  .f X.....'......
06-19 11:02:12.292: I/DEBUG(106):     5d4a9480 00000000 56be4298 0000000a 00000000  .....B.V........
06-19 11:02:12.292: I/DEBUG(106):     5d4a9490 00000001 5b18c629 00000000 00000000  ....)..[........
06-19 11:02:12.292: I/DEBUG(106):     5d4a94a0 00000000 00000000 0000000a 582085c0  .............. X
06-19 11:02:12.292: I/DEBUG(106): code around pc:
06-19 11:02:12.292: I/DEBUG(106):     5b1061f4 4010ea80 e92d4770 468841f0 68046886  ...@pG-..A.F.h.h
06-19 11:02:12.292: I/DEBUG(106):     5b106204 f7ff4608 4607ffe9 ea00b194 22000506  .F.....F......."
06-19 11:02:12.292: I/DEBUG(106):     5b106214 3035f854 00c5eb04 d00d4543 b922b15b  T.50....CE..[.".
06-19 11:02:12.292: I/DEBUG(106):     5b106224 f7ff4638 f040fe73 18ad0201 e7ef4035  8F..s.@.....5@..
06-19 11:02:12.292: I/DEBUG(106):     5b106234 e8bd4620 461881f0 81f0e8bd 4605b538   F.....F....8..F
06-19 11:02:12.292: I/DEBUG(106): code around lr:
06-19 11:02:12.292: I/DEBUG(106):     5b1061e8 ea8202cc ea6f1192 185823c1 4010ea80  ......o..#X....@
06-19 11:02:12.292: I/DEBUG(106):     5b1061f8 e92d4770 468841f0 68046886 f7ff4608  pG-..A.F.h.h.F..
06-19 11:02:12.292: I/DEBUG(106):     5b106208 4607ffe9 ea00b194 22000506 3035f854  ...F......."T.50
06-19 11:02:12.292: I/DEBUG(106):     5b106218 00c5eb04 d00d4543 b922b15b f7ff4638  ....CE..[.".8F..
06-19 11:02:12.292: I/DEBUG(106):     5b106228 f040fe73 18ad0201 e7ef4035 e8bd4620  s.@.....5@.. F..
06-19 11:02:12.442: D/Zygote(108): Process 20030 terminated by signal (11)
06-19 11:02:12.442: I/ActivityManager(304): Process com.example.prueba (pid 20030) has died.
06-19 11:02:15.362: W/ActivityManager(304): Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{4134bc20 com.example.prueba/.MainActivity}
```

My code

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.prueba"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.prueba.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.prueba;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebSettings.RenderPriority;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
        settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        settings.setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/LMS/clase_.htm");
    }
}
```

Without
settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
or
settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
it works ok.

I think it's a hardware problem

Anyone know something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

If you have enabled hardwareaccelerate in your app, it may cause this problem. You can disable hardwareaccelerate for WebView by this code:

`webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);`

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Was facing the same issue on emulators. Tracked it down to Hardware Acceleration. Disabling it for the whole app wasn't an option as it caused render issues, but it resolved the crash issue. Setting setLayerType according to this answer fixes it. Thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

I've faced the same problem and resolved it by:

```
webView.clearCache(false);
```

Hope I helped someone...

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the same exception thrown on my Droid Razr Maxx for an app I've been developing that uses a WebView and the settings: `settings.setUseWideViewPort(true)` and `settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true)`. Doesn't seem to be a problem on my Galaxy Tab 10.1.  It sometimes occurs when I change the orientation, but other things seem to set it off as well.

Comment: Did you come across a solution?  I don't quite know what you're suggesting as the solution with this response.

Comment: No better solution than to stay away from these methods when using certain hardware.