# Webview crash with simple HTML and throw JNI error

Tags: android, webview, hardware-acceleration

[image]
 Hi,i try to load an webview and i dont know why some HTML make app crash with the logs above.i have to say that the html is really simple

```html
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        font-size: 14;
        text-align: justify;
        max-width: 100%;
        word-break: break-all;
        word-break: break-word
    }
    
    img {
        display: inline;
        height: auto;
        max-width: 100%;
    }
    
    iframe {
        display: inline;
        height: auto;
        max-width: 100%;
    }
</style>
<html>

<body>
    <p align="justify" line-height="1.5">
        <p class="p1"><span class="s1" style="caret-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(26, 26, 26, 0.301961); -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);"><font color="#000000" face="sans-serif" size="3">[ TxxxxY]&nbsp;</font></span></p>
        <p class="p1"><span class="s1" style="caret-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(26, 26, 26, 0.301961); -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);"><font color="#000000" face="sans-serif" size="3">xxxx,&nbsp;</font></span></p>
        <p class="p1"><span class="s1" style="caret-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(26, 26, 26, 0.301961); -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);"><font color="#000000" face="sans-serif" size="3">xxxxy.&nbsp;</font></span></p>
        <p class="p1"><span class="s1" style="caret-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(26, 26, 26, 0.301961); -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);"><font color="#000000" face="sans-serif" size="3">* xxxxxx9.&nbsp;</font></span></p>
        <p class="p1"><span class="s1" style="caret-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(26, 26, 26, 0.301961); -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);"><font color="#000000" face="sans-serif" size="3">*xxxxxxố 5&nbsp;</font></span></p>
        <p class="p1"><span class="s1" style="caret-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(26, 26, 26, 0.301961); -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);"><font color="#000000" face="sans-serif" size="3">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx!</font></span></p>
        <p class="p1"><span class="s1" style="caret-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(26, 26, 26, 0.301961); -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);"><font color="#000000" face="sans-serif" size="3"><br></font></span></p>
    </p>
</body>

</html>
```

and the load weview method

```
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
            webView.setLayerType(webView.isHardwareAccelerated() ? View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE : 
           View.LAYER_TYPE_NONE, null);
        } else {
            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        }
```

webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", html, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "utf-8", "");

I think it look like something about JNI.so please any suggest about this

Comment: it's happend on some devices,not all

Comment: i bet it is error cause of HardwareAccelerated cause it not crash all the time

Comment: I can confirm that setting android:hardwareAccelerated="false" in manifest gets rid of the issue, but its not a solution since that messes up rendering of activity views. But seems to be related to WebView and hardware acceleration. Did you happen to solve this?

Comment: @AlexVPerl : hi, i was research for the answer so long.and this is the result
1 : maybe the problem is my webview is inside of a nested scrollview
2 : my partner just found out the device's ROM have been changed by default so i guess its the problem of hardware.
We decide to skip this cause no report on Crashlytic about this problem and only crash on our test device.1 more reason to skip this is it took to much time for nothing

Comment: thanks for reply. Issue in my case started happening on emulators after recent Android Studio update. I was able to resolve it by disabling hardware acceleration for web view only: webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null), more info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17187338/android-fatal-signal-11-sigsegv-in-webviewcorethre

Comment: @AlexVPerl disable hardware_acceleration make webview very slow in common case.AFAIK, most device today can using hardware_acceleration and the webview HTML is huge,maybe it will throw ANR or maybe crash ( i faced it already).and thanks you btw and i already tryed it on my project.have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of the JNI error, but I tried your html with this approach and it worked fine.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview)
    web.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    web.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/myhtml.html");
}
```

May be try running in a different emulator or device. It might be emulator specific issue

Comment: oh yes,sorry cause my mistake.it only error on some devices not all device.that's the weird part :(